# What is the Vapnik-Chervonenkis dimension of sigmoidal functions?

Tags: probability-theory, functional-analysis

Consider the following class of functions: $F=\{f_w:R^d \rightarrow [a,b], f_w(x)=\sigma(w^Tx), \forall x\in R^d\}$, where $\sigma(\cdot)$ is a sigmoidal function (e.g. tanh, or sigmoid so it has bounded outputs).

I would like to know what is the VC dimension of $F$?

I know that if $\sigma(\cdot)$ was replaced by $sign(\cdot)$ then the answer would be $d$. I also know that the VC dimension of $F$ cannot be smaller than this. I'm hoping that it would still be $d$ or a constant multiple of $d$?

Comment: How do you define the shattering dimension of a class of real-valued functions? And by the way the VC dimension of $d$-dimensional halfspaces is $d+1$.

Comment: Whatever threshold you use gives half-spaces. It doesn't matter how complicated the sigmoid function is because it is monotone. This is an exercise. It is not research level.

Comment: @DouglasZare: Thank you! It's clear now.